# Switching on the diode for some time, as well as execution of the next program in Arduino

Tags: arduino

[The circuit made in tinkercad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpMLk.png)
I use the relay, because I have only 4 wires to led diode and this two switches.

```
int led = 12; // red led
int s1 = 9; //switch 1
int s2 = 10; //switch 1
int k1 = 3; // first blue led
int k2 = 2; // second blue led
int y1 = 11; // relay
unsigned long startTime1 = 0;
unsigned long startTime2 = 0;
const int led1Duration = 6000; // first blue led time
const int led2Duration = 12000; // second blue led time

void setup()
{
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(k1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(k2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(y1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s1, INPUT);
  pinMode(s2, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(s1) == HIGH and digitalRead(s2) == LOW)
  { 
    digitalWrite(k1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(y1, HIGH);
    startTime1 = millis(); 
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
  
  if (digitalRead(s2) == HIGH and digitalRead(s1) == LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(k2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(y1, HIGH);
    startTime2 = millis(); 
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
  
  if (digitalRead(k1) == HIGH && (millis() - startTime1 >= led1Duration)) 
  {
    digitalWrite(k1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(y1, LOW);
  }
  if (digitalRead(k2) == HIGH && (millis() - startTime2 >= led2Duration)) 
  {
    digitalWrite(k2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(y1, LOW);
  }
  
  if (digitalRead(k1) == HIGH and digitalRead(k2) == LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(200);
  }
  if (digitalRead(k2) == HIGH and digitalRead(k1) == LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(500);
  }
  if (digitalRead(k2) == HIGH and digitalRead(k1) == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
}
```

Is there easier way to do that, cause when I assembled it the switches work very slow that blue led turn on after some time. Next I use the esp2866 but the relay for 3V doesn't turn on. How can I make it to work?

Comment: Don't use `delay` anywhere. Use `millis` for all timings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Peter is true : avoid blocking delay code.

here is an example : I have a little simplified your code and added else if to make it more readable.

update1 :

```
   int led = 12; // red led
int s1 = 9; //switch 1
int s2 = 10; //switch 1
int k1 = 3; // first blue led
int k2 = 2; // second blue led
int y1 = 11; // relay
unsigned long startTime1 = 0;
unsigned long startTime2 = 0;
unsigned long t200 = 200;
unsigned long t500 = 500;
const int led1Duration = 6000; // first blue led time
const int led2Duration = 12000; // second blue led time


void setup()
{
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(k1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(k2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(y1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(s1, INPUT);
  pinMode(s2, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(s1) && !digitalRead(s2)) {
    digitalWrite(k1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(y1, HIGH);
    startTime1 = millis();
    blinkLed200();
  } else if (!digitalRead(s1) && digitalRead(s2)) {
    digitalWrite(k2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(y1, HIGH);
    startTime2 = millis();
    blinkLed500();
  }

  if (digitalRead(k1) && (millis() - startTime1 >= led1Duration)) {
    digitalWrite(k1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(y1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }

  if (digitalRead(k2) && (millis() - startTime2 >= led2Duration)) {
    digitalWrite(k2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(y1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
}

void blinkLed200() {
  if (millis() - t200 > 200) { //tick every 200mS
    t200 = millis();
    digitalWrite(led, !digitalRead(led));
  }
}

void blinkLed500() {
  if (millis() - t500 > 500) { //tick every 500mS
    t500 = millis();
    digitalWrite(led, !digitalRead(led));
  }
}
```

The 3V relays have a very low resistance and I am not sure that the digital outputs are powerful enough. Personally I always switch relays via a transistor.

Comment: First of all thanks for help. I test the code and it works, but the LED first blink bright next only very weakly. How to fix it?

Comment: I improved your code: I hope it will calm the LED :-).